# A question for Nearest

Tags: nearest

Assume that I want to get nearest 10 points of a thousand random points in a given area to original point in three-dimensional coordinate system.
Does anyone know how the `Nearest` Work? What algorithm does it base on in mathematica?

Comment: The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) (look under Options/Method) implies that the default for numerical 3D vector data is a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) algorithm.

Comment: @SimonWoodsSi, cool, thx for giving this info.